# This address has been modified. Verify the changes and resubmit

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-developer

App Store Connect now requires the bank account holder’s address.
However when I try to add my address to my bank account on AppStore Connect I get an error saying:
**This address has been modified. Verify the changes and resubmit**

I tried clicking save multiple times and changing the address but nothing works.
Does anyone else have this issue? Anyone knows how this can be fixed?
Thank you

Comment: Same thing is happening to me today. Must be a bug in their system

Answer (score 6):

How many times did you click save button? I had the same issue and I saw this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/112590

I had to click it like 4 times or something. Make sure you don't close the window or leave the page. It's definitely a bug.

Comment: omg, bug is still unfixed for so many years

Comment: Seriously man.. need to click 4 times for me